# Easy database tool (the more gui the better)

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, database

So a friend of mine wants to set up a database for managing his investigation data. But he does not know any programming. So i offered a little help but also want to make sure that he could manage his stuff for when I am not around.

Basically I am looking for a database application that would be somewhat comparable to microsoft access, meaning i can setup the database and some forms. I know i could set up mysql and http server, but i am looking for a solution that has the most gui possible and is not dependent on servers so he could move the database easily to another workstation.

What would you recommend dear ubuntu fellows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Install [**openoffice.org-base**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openoffice.org-base) [image: Install openoffice.org-base]
- After installation it will be found under **Applications>>Office>>OpenOffice.org Database**

[image]

Comment: @ everybody: more options are ewlcome ;-)

Comment: LibreOffice is better...

Comment: I had problems installing it from that site you listed

Answer (score 5):

Nice, thanks for all the answers!

I also just found a software called **Kexi**. So people vote, which one of the options would you recommend more?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexi

[image: Kexi Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Another GUI database option is [**glom**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/glom) [image: Install glom]. Its interface is loosely based on FileMaker Pro, and it uses a PostgreSQL back-end.

- [Homepage](http://www.glom.org/)
- [Screenshots](http://www.glom.org/wiki/index.php?title=Screenshots)
- [User Guide](http://library.gnome.org/users/glom/unstable/)

Answer (score 1):

use sqlite + firefox plugin sqlitemanager, available at http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager

you can also use standalone gui to manage sqlite, sqliteman or sqlite database browser, both are in ubuntu repositories.